# Can an Rmd file be executed without generating a report or .md file?

Tags: r, r-markdown

When data munging I often use .Rmd files rather than R scripts, because the .Rmd files are more human readable. Is there a way that I can execute the .Rmd file without generating a report or .md of any kind?

When I execute .Rmd files from a makefile I use

```
Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('file.Rmd')" # which generates a report
Rscript -e "knitr::knit('file.Rmd')" # which generates an .md file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `knitr::purl` to extract the R code and run that.  For example,

```
Rscript -e "f <- tempfile(); knitr::purl('file.Rmd', output = f); source(f, echo = TRUE)"
```

Don't use `tempfile()` for `f` if you want to keep the script, use something like `file.R`.